# Bug with particle simulation

Tags: rendering, animation, particles, eevee-render-engine

I want to make a render of a car drifting, with the smoke emitting from a mesh parented to the rear tires. There are also wind force fields parented to the car to make the smoke-mesh rise up into the sky as it is emit. After baking, the viewport looks like this:

[image]

But after rendering, the smoke looks like this throughout the animation:

[image]

I've messed around with the wind and physics of the smoke mesh but I believe it is a problem with the rendering settings since the animation looks completely different in the render than in the viewport. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem has to do with your baking. Try baking all dynamics and also play around with the wind force fields because their strength might also be the issue.